# How to add Icon to the items of optionMenuGrp -Pyhotn for maya 2018?

Tags: python, maya

I want to have text and icons in the option menu ,I tried using the flag (image) for the optionMenuGrp command ,but I can't seem to get it right, here is the code I've been working on :

```
    import maya.cmds as cmds 



class ctrl_UI(object):

    @classmethod
    def display(cls,development=True):
        if cmds.window("ctrl_UI_window",exists=True):
            cmds.deleteUI("ctrl_UI_window")
        if development and cmds.windowPref("ctrl_UI_window", exists=True):
            cmds.windowPref("ctrl_UI_window", remove=True)
        cls.main_window=cmds.window("ctrl_UI_window",sizeable=False,rtf=True,mnb=False,mxb=False,t="Create Controllers") 
        main_layout=cmds.formLayout(p=cls.main_window)


       # Shap layout 
        shape_layout=cmds.rowLayout(p=main_layout,nc=1)
        cmds.formLayout(main_layout ,e=True ,af=(shape_layout,"top",4))
        cmds.formLayout(main_layout ,e=True ,af=(shape_layout,"left",4))

        cls.cShape=cmds.optionMenuGrp(l="Controller Shapes") 
        cmds.menuItem(i="C:\Users\HHCL\Documents\maya\2018\prefs\icons\Icon1.jpeg")
        cmds.menuItem(l="Cube",i="G:\Elham\scripts\Key tools\Icon2.jpeg")
        cmds.menuItem(l="Sphere",i="G:\Elham\scripts\Key tools\Icon1.jpeg")
        cmds.menuItem(l="Triangle",i="G:\Elham\scripts\Key tools\Icon2.jpeg")
        cmds.menuItem(l="Square",i="G:\Elham\scripts\Key tools\Icon1.jpeg")
        cmds.menuItem(l="Ring",i="G:\Elham\scripts\Key tools\Icon2.jpeg")
        cmds.menuItem(l="Half Circle",i="G:\Elham\scripts\Key tools\Icon1.jpeg")
        cmds.menuItem(l="Two Pin",i="G:\Elham\scripts\Key tools\Icon2.jpeg")
        cmds.menuItem(l="Quad Pin",i="G:\Elham\scripts\Key tools\Icon1.jpeg")
        cmds.menuItem(l="Locatore",i="G:\Elham\scripts\Key tools\Icon2.jpeg")
        cmds.menuItem(l="Single Arrow",i="G:\Elham\scripts\Key tools\Icon1.jpeg")
        cmds.menuItem(l="Double Arrow",i="G:\Elham\scripts\Key tools\Icon2.jpeg")
        cmds.menuItem(l="Four Arrow",i="G:\Elham\scripts\Key tools\Icon1.jpeg")
        cmds.menuItem(l="Pointer Arrow",i="G:\Elham\scripts\Key tools\Icon2.jpeg")
        cmds.menuItem(l="Arrow Head",i="G:\Elham\scripts\Key tools\Icon1.jpeg")
        cmds.menuItem(l="Plus",i="G:\Elham\scripts\Key tools\Icon2.jpeg")

        cmds.showWindow("ctrl_UI_window")
if __name__ =="__main__":
    c=ctrl_UI()
    c.display()
```

I feel like I'm missing something,but I can't put may hand on it 
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Icons can be displayed with the image flag on menuItems.
The image flag requires a string of the path to the icon.
Maya optionMenuGrp controls seem to suppress the image flag and others (e.g. -cc etc.)

An additional mistake in your code it that you are using `single backwards slashes` "\".
Change it to `forward slashes` "/" or use `double backslashes` "\\" for path separators.

`\t` - would be a tab-key for instance
`\n` - would be a new-line-character

Due to this problem the paths cannot be found but instead of an error Maya just ignores the wrong image paths.

Also a recommendation if you want to make use of this script on other computers as well, don't use absolute paths but put the icons into your scripts package and generate the full path depending on where the package lies on disk.

EDIT: after trying to fix the backwards slashes it turns out that Maya ignores images when menuItem controls are added to an optionMenuGrp. Images still work in an optionMenu (for main menu controls in windows for instance)
A suggestion would be to switch to Qt which comes with maya in the form of PySide/PySide2 and use QComboBox instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but didn't work .
I tried both ways and still nothing 
If you could please try out the code and take a pic of the output

Comment: @Elham_Amer  You are right, apologies. It seems some flags like image, cc and others are suppressed when the item is in an optionMenuGrp.

I haven't used maya UI elements in a long while. You should have a look at `Qt (PySide2)`. You have much more flexibility there with Qt Wigets.
Your equivalent of that would be the `QComboBox` which already supports the display of icons.